# How do I make the following Java code I created to a driver and call method/class?

Tags: java, driver, call

I just recently finished the following program. Now we were asked to make the following code in the snipet that I have presented into a class that calls from the driver program, but I don't know as to how that would look, how it would work, or the terminology needed to do this.

```
/**
 * Will Calculate the Area of Given Shapes.
 * 
 * @author Adrian Miranda
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */

import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Area_Shapes
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
      int Shape;
      String A = "The Area is ";

      double Area;
      double Base;
      double Height;
      double q1;
      double q2;
      double radius;
      double Length;
      char response;



      do
      { 
         System.out.println(" Enter A Shape 1 = triangle 2 = square 3 = rhombus 4 = circle 5 = rectangle: ");
         Shape = stdIn.nextInt();
         if (Shape == 1)
         {

            System.out.println("Enter Base: ");
            Base = stdIn.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter Height: ");
            Height = stdIn.nextDouble();

            Area = (Base * Height)/ 2 ;
            System.out.println( A + Area);
            System.out.println(" Enter Another Shape? (y/n): ");
            response = stdIn.next() .charAt(0);
         }

         else if (Shape == 2)
         {
            System.out.println("Enter length ");
            Length = stdIn.nextDouble();


            Area = Length * Length;
            System.out.println( A + Area);
            System.out.println(" Enter Another Shape? (y/n): ");
            response = stdIn.next() .charAt(0);

         }

         else if (Shape == 3)
         {
            System.out.println("Enter q1: ");
            q1 = stdIn.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter q2: ");
            q2 = stdIn.nextDouble();

            Area = q1 * q2 * 0.5 ;
            System.out.println( A + Area);
            System.out.println(" Enter Another Shape? (y/n): ");
            response = stdIn.next() .charAt(0);;
         }
         else if (Shape == 4)
         {
            System.out.println("Enter radius ");
            radius = stdIn.nextDouble();


            Area = radius * Math.PI * radius;
            System.out.println( A + Area);
            System.out.println(" Enter Another Shape? (y/n): ");
            response = stdIn.next() .charAt(0);

         }
         else if (Shape == 5)
         {

            System.out.println("Enter Base: ");
            Base = stdIn.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter Height: ");
            Height = stdIn.nextDouble();

            Area = (Base * Height) ;
            System.out.println( A + Area);
            System.out.println(" Enter Another Shape? (y/n): ");
            response = stdIn.next() .charAt(0);
         }
         else
         {
            System.out.println("error, invalid shape, please enter a square triangle or rhombus.");
            System.out.println(" Enter Another Shape? (y/n}: ");
            response = stdIn.next() .charAt(0);;
         }
      }while (response == 'y');
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, you should remove the `main(...)` method from the `Area_Shapes` class. Create a constructor in `Area_Shapes` that accepts the necessary parameters. Create a new class (e.g., `ShapesDriver`) that has a `main(...)` method. After collecting the information in the driver, instantiate the `Area_Shapes` class.

I would actually create multiple Shape classes rather than a single class that lumps everything together, but that is larger refactoring (but more OO-like). I would also make a method to calculate and display the results rather than doing the work in the constructor.

Nonetheless, the basic conceptual approach (**edit**: added an example loop to the driver class)

```
public class Area_Shapes {
   public Area_Shapes(int shape, double l1, double l2)
   {
      double area;
      switch (shape) {
        case 1:
         area = (l1 * l2) / 2;
          System.out.println("A triangle has an area of: " + area);
          break;

       ...
      }
   }
}
```

Driver Class

```
public class Driver {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
     boolean keepGoing = true;
     do {
       //collect shape information 
       System.out.println("Enter your shape (1 = triangle ...");
       shape = stdIn.nextInt();

       // based upon the shape, collect the inputs
       double inp1, inp2;
       switch (shape) {
         case 1:
           // inp1 is the base, inp2 is the height
           System.out.println("Enter Base: ");
           inp1 = stdIn.nextDouble();
           System.out.println("Enter Height: ");
           inp2 = stdIn.nextDouble();
         break;
       }  //switch shape

       // create a shape area instance; this calculates the
       //   area and outputs the answer  
       Shape_Area sa = new Shape_Area(shape, inp2, inp2);

       // prompt the user to enter another shape
       if (user_wants_to_stop) {
         keepGoing = false;
       }
     } while (keepGoing)
   } // main()
}
```

Comment: So, a couple questions here. One, it seems to me that in the area, you have already given the numbers for area, but, I want the user to be able to input them him/herself . 2 How would I be able to make the whole program loop. 3 in the driver class, can you explain to me the way in which that line the Shape_Area sa= new....... works and what it is purpose. and Finally, 4, how is the program running, in terms of when inserting it into the non driver class, how is it functioning how, or what is calling from the driver class in order to give the area and produce the end result?

Comment: @A.Miranda: 1. This driver is prompting for input. 2. Add a loop around the input area, and ask at the end (similar to what you have in the Shape_Area class now). 3. You create a new Shape_Area object. The way you have your current Shape_Area code (adjustments pointed out in the answer), you switch on the Shape, and display output; this would leverage the same approach. 4. don't understand the question.

Comment: For question 4, I apologize, I did word it oddly, but I mean as to how the program is running in terms of the calling and driver method. I'm new to coding so I am having trouble following the terminology and as to what does what and how it works in terms of producing the end result. Meaning how is the driver class interacting with the other one?

Comment: The Driver class is instantiating a new Shape_Area object on a given run after it has collected the information for a specific shape. Since it passes the entered shape and the inputs to the Shape_Area class through the constructor, the Shape_Area class needs only to perform the calculations and display the results.

Comment: Thank you so much, thanks to you, I have been able to get it to work and now know how to use the driver call method.